# Using the passed Context in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

In my ArrayAdapter class I capture the context passed in.  Then int the getView method, I have this if statement:

```
if(m.getSide() == RED) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(lc.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_bouy));
    Log.d("MA", "HERE");
} else if(m.getSide() == BLACK) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(lc.getResources().getColor(R.color.black_bouy));
}
```

(lc is the Context I grab from the Constructor)

If I just use Color.red, it works find.  All examples I've seen use ghet getResources..., but from within an activity.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create adapter, you pass a *Context* to constructor. In *getView()* you can call *getContext().getResources().get*... Is this what you were looking for?

<s>Also, @MahdeTo is right: you seem to keep a live reference to context - don't! You'll leak your context. If you absolutely must, use [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)<Context> and check for *null*, but I don't see why you would have to.</s>

**UPD:** Not really a problem with `Adapter`s (tnx to @Arhimed and @Rperryng for pointing this out) since their proper usage ensures their lifecycle doesn't exceed that of their `Context`, so it's ok to store a live link to a `Context` [*even if the adapter itself has a live ref in the `Context` -- GC is pretty smart, isn't fooled by circular refs]*. Nevertheless, there's no need to do that in this case: `ArrayAdapter.getContext()` is there for this exact purpose - so you can access resources and get an `Inflater` when you need one to build views in `getView()`

Comment: Awesome.  That did it!  It didn't work at first, but after a clean and re-build, it worked like a champ. Thank you both.

Comment: Interesting, when looking at the source code for the arrayAdapter https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java , it seems they keep a hard reference to the context object passed to the constructor

Comment: @Rperryng yeah, you and Arhimed are right, should not cause any problems having a Context linked in an adapter -- unless the adapter itself is leaked (or retained between activity recreations for some reason), but that would be a different problem.

Answer (score 10):

Well, actually passing a `Context` instance into adapter and keeping its reference should not be a source of any problems (like memory leaks, etc). I think so because if you check sources for, say, `ArrayAdapter<T>`, then you'll see it also accepts `Context` in constructor and (what is more important) it keeps a strong reference to it via private member `mContext` and has a getter for it - `getContext()`. It also does not have any code that could somehow unlink that `Context` from the reference, so it lives there as long as the adapter lives.

However in terms of performance I would define colors in your custom adapter constructor and then just use them directly in the `getView()` without the need to call `getContext().getResources().getColor()` many times.

Comment: Hm, yes, took a look at the code, I think you're right, no WeakReferences or any other precaucions there. Adapters get destroyed when activities so it's safe to keep a reference to the activity in adapter. Still, this would be redundant since there already is one :)

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of resource loading use Context.getApplicationContext() the static method to get a context that does not belong to a view. This way you avoid potential memory leaks.