# How to access Activity object in Adapter class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

How can i access object of activity in base adapter class. I used adapter class as adapter for my list-view. I want to access textview which is outside the listview but listview and textview are in same activity. I tried in adapter class like this:

```
            holder.grandTotal = (TextView) ShopCartActivity.findViewById(R.id.txtGrandTotal);
        holder.grandTotal.setText(String.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(grandTotal)));
```

But error is coming on this syntax:

```
ShopCartActivity. //ERROR
```

I tried like this too:

```
ShopCartActivity.this or ShopCartActivity.class
```

I tried this in constructor of adapter class it works (But value is not calculated yet) but when i put it in getView() method in which my all calculations are happening, its not working.

Basically i want to set value of textview after loop returns the value in base adapter. Is there a way i can access the object with findviewbyid method?

Comment: Pass the context to you adapter class constructor. And use the context afterwards like this `context.findViewById(R.id.txtGrandTotal);`

Comment: I passed the context in constructor its works there but not in getView method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass context when you create your adapter, Use that context to get the inflated view.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
```

Then in Adpater Class constructor :

```
public Adapter(Context context){
context.findViewById(R.id.textview);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your method is short and simple

Comment: Never pass contexts to adapter. It is a memory leak.

Comment: Holding context in adapter class doesn't result in memory leak. For clarification check answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037370/using-the-passed-context-in-an-arrayadapter

Answer (score 5):

You **should not** try to access an activity from within an adapter. It is bad programming. If you want to pass some value to the Activity and do some action in that, use some call back mechanism(Abstract class or interface) to pass value to the activity and then let the activity update the `TextView`'s text.

Sample code using an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AdapterHandler
{
    public void updateText(String text) {}
}
```

Then create an object of this class in the Adapter:

```
public AdapterHandler adapterhandler;
```

Then in the `Activity` set the handler, after you initialize the adapter:

```
adapter.adapterhandler = new AdapterHandler() {
    @Override
    public void updateText(String text) {
        ShopCartActivity.this.grandTotal.setText(text);
    }
};
```

And then in the adapter, where required, call it like:

```
if (this.adapterhandler != null) {
    this.adapterhandler.updateText(String.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(grandTotal)));
}
```

Code is relatively long, but this is the proper and far more scalable way to do it.

Comment: little confused explain more!

Comment: this.adapterhandler != null become null if i put it in click method inside getView() ?

Comment: Post the code in the Activity where you initialise and set the adapter. You must be doing something wrong there.

Comment: Oh wait, that maynot be the issue. Inside the click method you have to do it like `AdapterClassName.this.adapterhandler` (See my answer above, the same way as I have done in `updateText` override in Activity)

Comment: i tried it but still error, anyway i found the short solution below thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the context from the Activity you could get the TextView and other Views outside of the ListView like this:

```
// Get the rootView from the activity
final View rootView = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

// Get the textView from the rootView
TextView mTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

// Do something with it
mTextView.setText("Hello my friend!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send any of object from class before you set adapter when you call constructor and then can receive these params in the adapter.

```
final ChannelsAdapter channelAdapter = new ChannelsAdapter(allChannelList, SoftKeyboard.this);
channelRecyclerView.setAdapter(channelAdapter);
```